# Raw query to Ormlite (JOINS,GROUPBY) correct way

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

i am using ormlite version 4.46 I am able to get the desired result when i run a raw query but somehow the result is null when i am trying it in ormlite can someone please explain where i am making a mistake.

Snippet:

```
           String query=
                "SELECT Products.* FROM "+DBConst.TABLE_PRODUCTS
                        +" INNER JOIN "+DBConst.TABLE_OFFERS_MAPPING
                        +" ON Products."+DBConst.PROD_ID+" = OffersMapping."+DBConst.OFFERS_PRODUCT_ID
                        +" WHERE "+DBConst.OFFERS_OFFER_ID+ " = "+offerId+
                        " GROUP BY "+DBConst.PROD_PARENT_PRODVAR_ID;

        GenericRawResults<Product> rawResults = productDao.queryRaw(query, productDao.getRawRowMapper());

        //produces this query:SELECT Products.* FROM Products INNER JOIN OffersMapping ON Products._id = OffersMapping.product_id WHERE offer_id = 141 GROUP BY variant_id
        List<Product> prodList = rawResults.getResults();

        rawResults.close();
```

Gives me desired result....
Now to ormlite

```
    Dao<Product, String> productDao = helper.getProductDao();

    Dao<OfferMapping, String> offerMappingDao = helper.getOfferMappingDao();

    try {

        QueryBuilder<Product, String> productQb = productDao.queryBuilder();
        QueryBuilder<OfferMapping, String> offerQb = offerMappingDao.queryBuilder();
        //to sort the offer id accordingly
        offerQb.where().eq(DBConst.OFFERS_OFFER_ID, offerId);

        productQb.where().eq(DBConst.PROD_ID, new ColumnArg(DBConst.OFFERS_PRODUCT_ID));

        productQb.join(offerQb);

        productQb.groupBy(DBConst.PROD_PARENT_PRODVAR_ID); 

        Constants.showLog("Query", "Query is "+productQb.query());//gets null here

        List<Product> prodList = productQb.query();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
```

Dont know where i am making a mistake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i am using ormlite version 4.46 I am able to get the desired result when i run a raw query but somehow the result is null when i am trying it in ormlite can someone please explain where i am making a mistake.

Sorry for the late response.  I would log the generated query from the ORMLite query-builder and then compare it with your hand generated query.  You can log the results of `productQb.prepareStatementString()` before the query is performed.  For more information see the [logging documentation](http://ormlite.com/docs/logging).

Let me know if ORMLite is doing something wrong.